# Where do I put my "undefined" function using a base.html template wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I am getting the error message `UndefinedError: 'mod' is undefined`

In this scenario, `card` is always between 0 and 51.

Notice there is a `base.html` template involved.

Where do I put the javascript in the following situation or can I construct it differently?

Javascript:

```
numbers = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suits = ['S','H','D','C']

function mod(card){
    return numbers[card%13]+suits[card%4]
}
```

HTML:

```
{% for card in cardlist %}
    <input type="radio" class="btn" name="person" value="{{ card }}"/>
    {%set temp=mod(card)%}temp
{% endfor %}
```

base.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% block head %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - BridgeToGo</title>
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd guess this is something to do with the scope of the JavaScript function. is `mod` function in the global scope?

Comment: `{%set temp=mod(card)%}` <= what is this syntax?  It looks like you are trying to call a `mod` method in something other than javascript.

Comment: Yes, I am calling mod() from  Jinja2 inside a template <html> in a loop. `{% for card in cardlist %}` ... `{% endfor %}` where cardlist is some integers from 0..51. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: `mod` function is in the <script> section below the html which is defined in the base.html template. I wonder if the base.html template needs to be redone.Do I need to put the mod function in the base.html, and if so, where?

Comment: You can't call a JavaScript function from jinja2. JavaScript runs in the browser, but jinja2 runs on the server. See [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/3113485)

Comment: It seems I must  do the mod() in my python. Pity.